# how to load browser specific external css files?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I need to add reference to a external css file in my HEAD of page.
But it should be added only for IE browser.

Is this possible ?

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/jfile.css" />

</head>
```

Comment: This question has been asked like 100 times, please search for your question before you add another to the duplicate heap, there is a link added above to 1 of them

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/jfile.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/Common/Css/ie6.css' type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/Common/Css/ie7.css' type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/Common/Css/ie8.css' type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```